# It seems to be deadlock .. two socket java code

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm doing an assignment which is to build two java codes communicating with each others by sockets. When I started build two basic codes (communicate once) It worked fine, but when I tried to make them keep communicating both Jammed!

Please forgive my lack of experience and help me..

My server code,

```
/*****************************************************************************************
 *
 *
 *
 ***************************************************************************************/

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class COMP_3270_Server implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket(3270);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A server built over " +
                    InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + " : " +
                    myServer.getLocalPort() + "\nWaiting for masseges...",
                    "succeed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            Socket channel = myServer.accept();
            BufferedReader incomes = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream outgoes = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());

            String mssg = null;

            do {
                mssg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("New Message: " + incomes.readLine());
                outgoes.print(mssg);
            } while (mssg != null);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The server will be closed now",
                    "Finish", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            channel.close();
            myServer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ops!, some thing went wrong. Please contect provider");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

and my client code,

```
/*************************************************************
 *
 *
 *
 * ***********************************************************/

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class COMP_3270_Client implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Socket channel = new Socket("localhost", 3270);
            BufferedReader incomes = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream outgoes = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected to: " +
                    channel.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " : " +
                    channel.getPort(), "succeed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            String mssg = "New client: " + channel.getLocalAddress().getHostName();
            outgoes.print(mssg);
            System.out.println("222");

            do {
                mssg = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("New Message: " + incomes.readLine());
                outgoes.print(mssg);
            } while (mssg != null);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The channel will be closed now",
                    "Finish", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            channel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ops!, some thing went wrong. Please contect provider");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

it's helped!!!! I'm almost done in my assignment.
U seems good with Socket issues! so, I want to take some benefits ;)

Do you have any idea how to detect if the message throw the buffer is null? I have tried several methods, but nothing worked!

if u wanna see my codes after your ( maybe some one will need it,

```
/*****************************************************************************************
*
***************************************************************************************/

import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class COMP_3270_Server
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
    ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket(3270);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "A server built over " + 
        InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() + " : " +
        myServer.getLocalPort() + "\nWaiting for a client...", "succeed", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    Socket channel = myServer.accept();     
    BufferedReader income = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
    PrintStream outgoes = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());

    String resp = " ";
    String mssg = " ";
    do
    {
        if (income.ready())
        {
            if(mssg.intern() == null)
            {
                int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                        "Client left sever, keep server alive?", "Client left",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) 
                {
                    resp = null;
                }
                else if (response == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION)
                {
                    resp = null;
                }
                else if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                {
                }
            }
            else
            {
                resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("New client message: " + mssg);
                outgoes.println(resp);
            }
        }
    }while (resp != null && mssg != null);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The server will be closed now", "Finish", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        channel.close();
        myServer.close();

    }
    catch (HeadlessException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "A string not supported", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "IP address not available", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Failed or interrupted I/O", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    } 
}
```

and

```
/*************************************************************
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * References   : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEDV0WlwXTs
 * ***********************************************************/

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class COMP_3270_Client
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        try
        {
            String ip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the IP you want to connect to: ");
            Socket channel = new Socket(ip, 3270);
            BufferedReader income = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream outgoes = new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());

            String strt = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Succeed! Connected. You can say something: ");
            outgoes.println(strt);

            String resp = " ";
            String mssg = " ";
            do
            {
                if (income.ready())
                {
                    mssg = income.readLine();

                    if(mssg.intern() == null)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Server closed!", "Session end",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        resp = null;
                        outgoes.println(resp);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("New server message: " + mssg);
                        outgoes.println(resp);                  
                    }
                }
            }while (resp != null && mssg != null);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "The channel will be closed now", "Finish", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);;
            channel.close();
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Wrong IP address or server reject connection", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Failed or interrupted I/O", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the programming world. First lesson is that you don't say `build two java codes` but `build two java classes` or `two java applications` or `two java programs`.

Comment: Let me guess - your client does send exactly one message to the server, after that both apps (client + server) terminate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading from the socket you use the `readLine` method. It will block until a complete line has been read, read more [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29). This *never happens* since when writing to the socket `print` is used.

Try to use `println` instead of `print` when writing to the socket.

Also why does your classes implement `Runnable`? This does not add anything, but just makes your code harder to read.

Please check your spelling - It's called a "messages" not a "masseges". And whats a "contect provider"?

Comment: yeah, thats great! :) There is a small tickbox below the '0'? You see it? Please use it. You can read more here http://stackoverflow.com/faq under the topic "How do I ask questions here".