# Socket in multithreading "deadlocked" Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, deadlock

I am trying to launch server and client thread on the same process, but seems like the server thread is blocking the client thread (or vice versa). I'm not allowed to use any global variable between those threads(like semaphore or mutex, since the client and the server thread are launched by upper-class that I don't have the access of).

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192733/it-seems-to-be-deadlock-two-socket-java-code) , but it still use two different process (two main function).

Here is a sample of my code

The server code:

```
public class MyServer implements Runnable{

    ServerSocket server;
    Socket client;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    public MyServer() throws IOException{
        server = new ServerSocket(15243, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            try {

                ArrayList<String> toSend = new ArrayList<String>();

                System.out.println("I'll wait for the client");
                client = server.accept();
                out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

                String inputLine;
                while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    toSend.add("answering : "+inputLine);
                }

                for(String resp : toSend){
                    out.println(resp);
                }

                client.close();
                out.close();
                in.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And the client code:

```
public class MyClient implements Runnable{

    Socket socket;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;

    public MyClient(){
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int nbrTry = 0;
        while(true){
            try {
                System.out.println("try number "+nbrTry);
                socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 15243);

                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                out.println("Hello "+nbrTry+" !! ");

                String inputLine;
                while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                }
                nbrTry++;
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the supposed upper-class launching those thread:

```
public class TestIt {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException{
        MyServer server = new MyServer();
        MyClient client = new MyClient();
        (new Thread(server)).start();
        (new Thread(client)).start();
    }
}
```

It gives me as output:

```
I'll wait for the client
Try number 0
```

And it stuck here. What should I do to keep both server and client code running?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't silently ignore exceptions! They are thrown for a reason. When you are trying to debug your code, should at minimum be printing the messages. Going forward, have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: FYI you ARE running both client and server together as they are both two separate threads. The problem is in your coding which I am using a debugger to figure out how to get it working like you want it to :P

Comment: Just a thought, the server takes some time to set up, and you are starting the client immediatly afterwards. You haven't set a timeout on MyClient, thats why it only tries once. It is constantly trying the first attempt

Comment: I tried to debug it. On the server thread, it stuck on `client = server.accept();` , on the client side, it stuck on `inputLine = in.readLine()`

Comment: Can you give us a couple of lines of expected output please?

Comment: @unholysampler Although I put back the logger code in catch block, no exception catched but thanks anyway.

Comment: @stas I added a Thread.sleep(1000) in the the client thread, same result :/

Comment: In the question you are suggesting that the problem is because they are on the same thread. So try and run them from two different processes and see what happens.

Comment: @Sanchit I'm expecting something like 

[Server] I'll wait for the client
[Client] try number 0
[Client] Hello 0 !!
[Server] answering : Hello 0 !!

[Server] I'll wait for the client
[Client] try number 1
[Client] Hello 1 !!
[Server] answering : Hello 1 !!

[Server] I'll wait for the client
[Client] try number 2
[Client] Hello 2 !!
[Server] answering : Hello 2 !!

Comment: okay wait for my answer. There are two ways you can achieve this. Either one client sending multiple requests or multiple clients sending requests to your server. Which one do you want?

Comment: @Sanchit I just want them to communicate indefinitely, like two people chating.

Comment: @stas I cannot create two different process. My work is just to create two thread, and give them to another class who will run them (to be clear, a class from a closed source library who will launch them). But I want my thread to communicate through socket.

Comment: 1) This doesn't really make sense. Why would you want the same program to communicate through a socket. 2) The server is not supposed to chat with a client, but the server is supposed to control messages between two clients. 3) Im just saying try it so see if that is the problem

Comment: @Sanchit Just one client sending multiple request.

Comment: @stas the "chat" is just a metaphore I used :) . I just want the server to be ready and give a prepared answer every time the client send a request. And sure, they are in the same program, but they are launched as different thread. I write a class A and B. I give them to class C. I have no idea about the implementation of C, and cannot change it. All I know is that C will just run A and B as different thread. But I need to send information between A and B. Among many IPC method, I choose to use socket communication, but there is that one problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be willing to take up your questions but basically you need to think through your logic a bit more carefully.

MyServer.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyServer implements Runnable {

  ServerSocket server;

  public MyServer() throws IOException {
    server = new ServerSocket(15243, 0, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {
        // Get a client.
        Socket client = server.accept();

        // Write to client to tell him you are waiting.
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("[Server] I'll wait for the client");
        // Let user know something is happening.
        System.out.println("[Server] I'll wait for the client");

        // Read from client.
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = in.readLine();

        // Write answer back to client.
        out.println("[Server] Answering : " + inputLine);

        // Let user know what it sent to client.
        System.out.println("[Server] Answering : " + inputLine);

        in.close();
        out.close();
        client.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

MyClient.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MyClient implements Runnable {

  Socket socket;
  PrintWriter out;
  BufferedReader in;

  public MyClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    int nbrTry = 0;
    while (true) {
      try {
        // Get a socket
        socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 15243);

        // Wait till you can read from socket.
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = in.readLine();
        //inputLine contains the text '[Server] I'll wait for the client'. means that server is waiting for us and we should respond.

        // Write to socket
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("[Client] Hello " + nbrTry + " !! ");

        // Let user know you wrote to socket
        System.out.println("[Client] Hello " + nbrTry++ + " !! ");

      } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
      } catch (IOException ex) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

TestIt.java

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestIt {

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws IOException {
    MyServer server = new MyServer();
    MyClient client = new MyClient();
    (new Thread(server)).start();
    (new Thread(client)).start();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is sort of the equivalent of multiple clients sending the server messages by the way. I did it this way because you could probably get more use out of it this way if you ever need to extend it.

Comment: :pokerface: it's almost the same code!!! You just removed the while loop. Pretty well then, since I want to send multiple line, I'll figure out a way to send it as a single line. Thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah, except that this code works :P And you have comments to know exactly how the logic works. :) I did a tiny bit more than just remove the while loop. I fixed a logic flaw. Anyways, Good luck!

Comment: Yup, you inversed something! It always gives you a good lesson when you stuck on a beginner's code for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Your client sends a string, then reads until the stream is exhausted:

```
                while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
```

BufferedReader.readLine() only returns null at the end of the stream, as I recall.  On a stream, it will block until input is available

Your server receives until the stream is exhausted, then sends back its response.

After sending one line, you now have:

- Your client waiting for a response.
- Your server still waiting for more data from the client.  But it doesn't send anything back until the end of the stream from the client (which never happens because the client is waiting for your response).